# While loop not initialiazing

Tags: c++, while-loop, getline

My while loop does not appear to be initializing. The file filename.csv is a CSV file with only one column of 2000 numbers between -1 and 1.  I've tried getline with both \n and \r.  Neither seem to work.  I'm not getting any output.

I'm quite new to C++ so it might be something very obvious.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

int main()
{    
    float rarray_train[2000];
    int rrow_train=0;
    ifstream  r_train("filename.csv");
    string rline_train;    

    while( getline(r_train,rline_train,'\n') )
    {
        rarray_train[rrow_train] = stof( rline_train.c_str() );
        cout<<rarray_train[rrow_train]<<endl;
        ++rrow_train;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Edit: Sorry about this.  I misspelt my file path.  Thanks for your help.  Don't know etiquette around here so if you think I should delete the question let me know.

Comment: A tip: Always reduce your code to a [mcve] before asking any questions about it. That either leads you to the answer, or at least makes for a better question.

Comment: use a debugger or some debugging statements to see how execution is flowing through your loop. Also check whether opening the file succeeded, and you should also have a condition to exit your loop after 2000 iterations

Comment: @Deduplicator it looks like a MCVE to me, apart from not including the input file of course

Comment: @Deduplicator What do you suggest I remove?

Comment: does this one column also does not end with ;? This might be an issue. Have you checked the content of rrow_train and whether your loop runs 1000 times? I would also suspect stof... Maybe, could you provide 5 lines of your file, so that we could test?

Comment: @MM As an example, why does he include `vector`, `sstream` or `stdlib.h`? Could be far worse, but could be better too.

Comment: an MCVE doesn't need a counter or an array...

Comment: @deduplicator *she.  I will now you pointed it out,

Comment: The most likely cause of the problem is that the file "filename.csv" does not exist in the directory where you are running your program. Add a line to check whether the file was opened successfully. `if (r_train.is_open()) { ... }`.

Comment: Well, there was no indication, and I guessed wrong ;-)

Comment: That's strange, I swear I just saw a glitch in the matrix. The OP updated her question.

Comment: This probably isn't the problem, but since you're in `std` namespace anyway, you might as well just use `endl`, so you don't have to worry about '\n' vs '\r\n'

Comment: @RSahu THanks very much for this.  I appear to have got the filepath misspelt.  Sorry about that

Comment: @ocket8888 You seem to have a misconception what `std::endl` does. `stream << std::endl` is exactly the same as `stream << '\n' << `std::flush`. In other words, only use `std::endl` if you might need the explicit manual flush, and have to output `'\n'`.

Comment: Oh, I thought the purpose of endl was to eliminate the need for a C++ program to know if it's running on Windows/DOS or *nix just to output to a terminal.

Comment: @ocket8888: If the stream is in text-mode, it does line-end-conversions where needed. In other words, only ever on windows, or some old and obsolete platforms.

Comment: hmmm. But what if I want 'incorrect' line endings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your code when there is no file `filename.csv` or it is empty yields no output. Running your code when the file exists gives the expected output.

PS: You don't need `.c_str()`.